# Due to error 0x80070057" The parameter is incorrect." SSIS job failed to run

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2017

I have a SSIS job which run well in SQL Server 2008 but no longer working in SQL Server 2017. The error message I get is:

> [Cannot create a task from XML for Task "Email", type "Microsoft.Script.Task" due to error 0x80070057" The parameter is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqhTK.png)

Kindly advise any solution for this problem. Thanks

Comment: Are you using [ActiveX scripting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/170715/5203)?

Comment: I think no, do you have any idea why it mentioned pass in parameter incorrect? Even though the config file is setup correctly

Comment: SSIS engine in SQL Server is version specific and is known to have poor backward compatibility (i.e. total lack of backward compatibility). You need to upgrade your SSIS packages to the correct version before re-deploying them on newer SQL Server versions.

Comment: This should get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages-using-the-ssis-package-upgrade-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have try to create new SSIS package file using script task with empty function and use sql server 2017 job to call on it and also faced same issues. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: What version of SSDT tools are you using? Make sure that it is the right version for SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score 3):

SSIS solutions that have been used on SQL Server 2008 R2, must be migrated to work properly on 2016/2017. The XML structure of the ssis packages is completely different and I believe 2008 packages only was supported until 2012/2014.

The process of doing this is basically.

1. Install VS2017 and newest version of SSDT
2. Open SSIS project and run migration wizard
3. Solve migration conflicts
4. Build and deploy

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting here because I've struggled as well with this issue, but on my SCD and I believe this might help someone.

I managed to resolve it by removing the precision of my datetime2(7)by converting it to a DateTime before entering the SCD component.

You can also try to reduce your varchar type fields from eg 4000 to 200 if possible which will allow your flow to run successfully.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the server where the job was running was missing the SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS). Installing the SSIS feature on the server has fixed this problem for me.